# Odoo 10 - Qweb - Testing boolean field for false

Tags: odoo-10, odoo, qweb

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312125/odoo-10-conditional-hide-show-of-kanban-view-image/48314622#48314622) deals with testing a specific field to conditionally display information in a qweb view.

The example uses `default_code` from `product.template`.

What shall be done to test if `sale_ok` is `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the boolean field is false you can use below condition

```xml
<t t-if="!record.sale_ok.raw_value">
```

Comment: Is it worth to mention that `sale_ok` must exist as field in the QWeb and not just in the model? Is that correct?

Comment: @M.E. yes, the field must exist in the view.